# windows 10 UWP PointerExited does not trigger on touch screen

Tags: c#, windows-10, uwp, windows-10-mobile

I'm using PointerEntered and PointerExited on my grid to change it's color when pointer is inside, and sometimes (most of time) PointerExited does not trigger on my w10m phone, I used break point to check that. Same with Poiner(Canceled/CaptureLost). It doesn't trigger even if I touch outside the grid, when pointer is 100% outside.

Any ideas how to fix that?

My code (if needed):

```
        private void ButtonPointerEntered(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var c = (ButtonGrid.Background as SolidColorBrush).Color;
            ButtonGrid.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(60, c.R, c.G, c.B));
        }

        private void ButtonPointerExited(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e) //Does not trigger
        {
            var c = (ButtonGrid.Background as SolidColorBrush).Color;
            ButtonGrid.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(0, c.R, c.G, c.B));
        }
```

XAML:

```
            <Grid PointerEntered="ButtonPointerEntered" Tapped="ButtonTapped"  x:Name="ButtonGrid" Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationForegroundThemeBrush}" PointerExited="ButtonPointerExited">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <TextBlock x:Name="IconTB" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" FontSize="18" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,3,0,0"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="TextTB" Grid.Row="1"  FontSize="13" HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords" TextAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,2"/>
            </Grid>
```

Comment: Touch *has* no pointer, as a concept. It has touch points to interact, but not the notion of a pointer hovering somewhere, so Entered/Exited is kind of a meaningless concept. You should probably only do the colour change when the user is actually using a mouse or similar pointing device.

Answer (score 0):

I started my app without debugging with visual studio and... It work 100% correct. So the problem was in debugging